# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.load. : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: python, xml, apache-spark, pyspark

This is the code in which I am getting error*

```
df=spark.read.format("xml").option("rowTag","Root").load("/content/xml")
```

I want to parse xml using pyspark without any other platform (i.e databricks or azure)
I had also tried by downloading the jar file of spark-xml form mvn repository  its code is

```
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("Apache spark using pyspark")\
.config("spark jars","C:/Users/baps/Downloads/spark-xml_2.12-0.9.0.jar")\
.config("spark.executor.extraClassPath","C:/Users/baps/Downloads/spark-xml_2.12-0.9.0.jar")\
.config("spark.executor.extraLibrary","C:/Users/baps/Downloads/spark-xml_2.12-0.9.0.jar")\
.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath","C:/Users/baps/Downloads/spark-xml_2.12-0.9.0.jar")\
.getOrCreate()
```

In this is also I am getting same error at line spark.read.format

This is the error I m getting every time

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-59ae75a30984> in <module>
----> 1 df=spark.read.format("xml").option("rowTag","Root").load("/content/spark_/sample_corrupted.xml")

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o125.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Failed to find data source: xml. Please find packages at
https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
       
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedToFindDataSourceError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:587)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:675)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:725)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:185)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xml.DefaultSource
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:661)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:661)
    at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:661)
    ... 15 more
```

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: sorry can you please answer me

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the `.` in `spark.jars`. Try changing

```
.config("spark jars","C:/Users/baps/Downloads/spark-xml_2.12-0.9.0.jar")
```

to

```
.config("spark.jars","C:/Users/baps/Downloads/spark-xml_2.12-0.9.0.jar")
```

Hope this helps!